# Unity3d Android app horizontal scale

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

My app scales vertically and cuts off right and left edges. How can I achieve the opposite? For example I have 16:9 portrait image. When I launch it on 16:10 screen in portrait orientation, it should fit horizontally and cut upper and lower edges off. Can I achieve that changing Manifest file? 
Thanks!

Comment: I think you can't. You can adjust the gameObject scale at runtime based on the information from `Screen.Width` and `Screen.Height`.

Comment: What do you mean by "scale"? The camera's field of view?